# google maps api json pass array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-maps-api-3

I have a google map which I am getting json data from. I want to automatically build a string that I can pass to the marker object. I get an error "invalid object initializer" in firebug when I do this. Does this make sense or is their a better way to handle this.

```
function buildMarkers(json) {

    $.each(json, function(z) {     
        var asdf;
        $.each(this, function(key,valueObj){
            //console.log(key + '---' + valueObj);
            asdf += key + ': ' + valueObj + ', ';
        });


        markers[z] = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map, 
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(this.school_lat,this.school_long),
                asdf
        });

etc....
```

Comment: looks like you're building a string, not key-value pairs

Comment: yes you're right, I want it to be object values... I believe?

Comment: which version of the GoogleMapsAPI?

Comment: I am using v3 of the api

Comment: Can you give an example of the JSON output?  You are going to have to put together all of the `MarkerOptions` and pass them to `Marker()` at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try building your json object like this:

```
var asdf = [];
$.each(this, function(key, valueObj) {
    asdf.push({key: key, value: valueObj});
});
```